# Android - Loading a different Layout depending on value selected from a Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-spinner

I have a spinner on my home page and when I select a value from the spinner and hit submit my next page loads up with several text boxes.

However, how can I get it so that differnt layouts are displayed according to the value selected from the spinner. I am trying to currently use if statements, however this only works for the first selection, any other causes the app to error out (The application has stopped unexpectedly ... Force close:

```
    String RefType = getIntent().getStringExtra("REFTYPE");
    if (RefType.equals("spinner_value_1"))
    {
       setContentView(R.layout.layoutvalue1);  
    }
    else if (RefType.equals("spinner_value_2"))
    {
       setContentView(R.layout.layoutvalue2); 
    }
```

Any help would be much appeciated.

Thanks

Comment: error out? and what is the error in the Logcat?

Comment: Hi, the error message I get is - The application has stopped unexpectedly ... Force close. Thanks

Comment: Error from LogCat...The stacktrace

Comment: To be honest there are quite a few errors in the logCat, not really sure which is relevent. Could you possible guide me as to roughly what I am looking for?

Comment: Clear your logcat messages before hitting the button you speak of. Hit the button and paste the first exception's stack trace (the whole stack trace!).

Comment: I imagine the error would be because you'd be trying to set the contentView twice, so you may need to change a variable in the `if` statement then call onCreate again. I'll add an answer and you can try

Comment: Boris I done as you mentioned and this is the first error message that I got - 01-15 20:03:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(225): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the error would be because you'd be trying to set the contentView twice, so you could try this:
Add `int layoutToLoad = 0;`*(change here) to the top of your class, this will help us determine what to load. Then in your onCreate:

```
if (layoutToLoad == 0)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.choiceLayout); //whatever the layout with the spinner is
    //alternatively you can make the spinner via code  
}
else if (layoutToLoad == 1))
{
    setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
}
else if (layoutToLoad == 2))
{
    setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
}
//etc
```

then where you're handling your onOptionSelected:

```
String RefType = getIntent().getStringExtra("REFTYPE");
if (RefType.equals("spinner_value_1"))
{
    layoutToLoad = 1;
    onCreate(null);  
}
else if (RefType.equals("spinner_value_2"))
{
    layoutToLoad = 2;
    onCreate(null);  
}
//etc
```

Comment: I just trued the above, however this doesn't seem to be working. Every time I try to select one of the options from the spinner and load up the next page, I simply get the same error message. Is there something that I may have missed?

Comment: well one problem I've just released re-reading it is that the int is declared as a string, so you could try changing that (I've edited the answer with a *)

Comment: I had already edited that, I also removed the additional ) from else if (layoutToLoad == 2))